# Custom fields in a workflow

Tags: workflow, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to add a custom field to the PurchTable in Dynamics AX 2012 and I would like to utilize it in the Purchase Order Workflow.

I have tried adding the field to the PurchTableDocument query which is supposed to drive the workflow, as well as recompiling the PurchTableDocument class.

Any help is appreciated.
Curt

Answer (score 1):

just thought I would follow up and add that this was resolved by generating incremental CIL and restarting the AOS.